# Using curl to send multiple url sms

Tags: php, mysql, url, curl, sms

I want send results to students in a school. I already have the results and each student's phone number in a mysql database. From my little research, I found out that curl is the most efficient way to send url sms. To send the result to each student, I used a while loop to select each student phone and result against the exam name in the database table (result). Now, the problem is that only one message is sent. I've tried checking the code again but could not find anything. Please how can I solve this problem? Below is my code:

```
class SendSMS
{
    private $url = 'http://www.domain.com/http/index.aspx?account=acct&password=pwd';  

function __construct()
{

}

// public function to commit the send
public function send($message,$recipient)
{
    $url_array= array(
                    'message'=>$message,
                    'sendto'=>$recipient
                );

    $url_string = $data = http_build_query($url_array, '', '&');

    // we're using the curl library to make the request
    $curlHandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url_string);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $responseBody = curl_exec($curlHandle);
    $responseInfo  = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);
    curl_close($curlHandle);

    return $this->handleResponse($responseBody,$responseInfo);
}


private function handleResponse($body,$info)
{
    if (substr($body, 0, 2) == "OK"){ // successful submission
        $_SESSION['success'] = "[$body]: Your SMS(s) have been sent";
        return true;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = "An error has occurred: [$body].";
        // error handling
        return false;
    }

}

}
```

Below is the while loop to send the multiple messages:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM result_table WHERE exam='".$_POST['examName']."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$std = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

while ($std = mysqli_fetch_array($std_query)) {
    $recipient = $std['parent_phone'];
    $sms = new SendSMS();
    $sms->send($msssg,$recipient,"header");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `curl_close($curlHandle);` closes the connection. Therefore...

1.) Pass an array/object of all the information from MySQL query to the function.

2.) Open curl connection.

3.) Loop the iterations and exec them all.

4.) Close the connection.

Better yet look at curl-multi, this doesn't reauth each time so should get you even better throughput. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: I'm new to php. Please, can you give me an example of how I can loop the   iteration and  exec the array of the result from the database?

Comment: You already are looping with your `while` statement. Just don't close the connection in the loop, close it after the loop.